# fetch text from a web site and displaying it back

Tags: python, screen-scraping

Currently, there's a game that has different groups, and you can play for a prize 'gold' every hour. Sometimes there is gold, sometimes there isn't. It is posted on facebook every hour ''gold in group2" or "gold in group6'', and other times there isn't a post due to no gold being a prize for that hour. I want to write a small script that will check the site hourly and grab the result (if there is gold or not, and what group) and display it back to me. I was wanting to write it in python as I'm learning it. Would this be the best language to use? And how would I go about doing this? All I can really find is information on extracting links. I don't want to extract links, just the text. Thanks for any and all help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [`urllib2`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) for getting html from a url and [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)/[`HTMLParser`](http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html)/etc to parse the html.  Then, you could use something like this as a starting point for the script:

```
import time
import urllib2
import BeautifulSoup
import HTMLParser

def getSource(url, postdata):
    source = ""
    req = urllib2.Request(url, postdata)
    try:
        sock = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    except urllib2.URLError, exc:
        # handle the error..
        pass
    else:
        source = sock.read()
    finally:
        try:
            sock.close()
        except:
            pass
    return source

def parseSource(source):
    pass
    # parse source with BeautifulSoup/HTMLParser, or  here...

def main():
    last_run = 0
    while True:
        t1 = time.time()
        # check if 1 hour has passed since last_run
        if t1 - last_run >= 3600:
            source = getSource("someurl.com", "user=me&blah=foo")
            last_run = time.time()
            parseSource(source)
        else:
            # sleep for 60 seconds and check time again.
            time.sleep(60)
     return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

Here is a good article about [parsing-html-with-python](http://unethicalblogger.com/2008/05/03/parsing-html-with-python.html)

Answer (score 1):

I have something similiar to what you have, but you left out what my main question revolves around. I looked at htmlparser and bs, but I am unsure how to do something like if($posttext == gold) echo "gold in so and so".. seems like bs deals a lot with tags..i suppose since facebook posts can use a variety of tags, how would i go about doing just a search on the text and to return the 'post' ??